# Add new Constructor to an existing Java Class via AspectJ

Tags: aspectj

Trying to clean up some nasty code, for which we dont have the source code. Imagine something like this:

```
public class Driver{

    private String paramA;
    private String paramB;

    new Driver(HugeAndOverbloatedObject object)     
    {
         paramA = object.getSubObject4711().getParamX();
         paramB = object.getSubObject4712().getParamY();
    }

}
```

This third library has this all over the place: tight coupling via constructors, eventhough the classes are hardly related. The rude combination of private members and forced constructor inheritance make the extension of the code virtually impossible without creating "sloppy" constructor parameter objects.

So I am trying to manipulate the classes via AspectJ and compile time weaving, so I can slim down on the constructors, to something like this:

```
Driver driver = new Driver("paramA", "paramB");
```

I think this should be possible, and I have made some progress. If I have something like this:

```
public aspect NewConstructor {
    Driver.new(String parameterA, String parameterB){
        //New Constructor Code
    }
}
```

and run this through the weaver I actually find a new constructor in the driver, but not quite as I expected.

*Issue: Unexpected third Parameter in the woven class*

I was hoping I can invoke it with two parameters:
    new Driver("paramA", "paramB")

Instead I need to invoke it with three parameters:
    new Driver("paramA", "paramB", new NewConstructor())

Why do I need to instantiate a new instance of the aspect and pass it as an argument? Can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something odd is going on here.  You should not need to add the aspect as a third argument to the constructor.  In fact, when I try this myself using the following class and aspect, I do not get any compile errors:

Java class:

package pack;

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver("paramA", "paramB");
    }
}
```

Aspect:

```
package pack;

public aspect NewConstructor {
    public pack.Driver.new(String parameterA, String parameterB){
    }
}
```

Are your Java class and aspect in different projects?  Are you using an aspect path and/or in path?  Are you using load time weaving?

If after doing a full build of your project you still see the probem, it's worth [raising a bug for AspectJ](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: Hi, the toolcahin was mis configured - All OK. Thanks!